# std::function const correctness

Tags: c++, std-function, const-correctness

Suppose I have a callable type like so:

```
struct mutable_callable
{
    int my_mutable = 0;
    int operator()() { // Not const
        return my_mutable++;
    }
};
```

Note that `mutable_callable` has a non-const `operator()` that modifies a member variable.....

Now suppose I create a `std::function` out of my type:

```
std::function<int()> foo = mutable_callable{};
```

Now I can do this:

```
void invoke(std::function<int()> const& z)
{
    z();
}

int main()
{
    invoke(foo); // foo changed.....oops
}
```

Now as far as I can tell `std::function`s `operator()` is `const` as per:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()

So my gut feeling is that you shouldn't be able to do this.....

But then looking at:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function

This doesn't seem to put any constraints on whether or not the callable type has a constant `operator()`......

So my question is this: I am correct in assuming that `std::function<int()> const&` is essentially the same thing as `std::function<int()>&` that is there is no actually difference between the behavior of the two......and if that is the case why is it not `const` correct?

Comment: @MaxLanghof No.....`std::function` has the equivalent to a `struct a{ std::any x; };` in it.....

Comment: Here is a small snippet of the internals of the MSVC `std::function` implementation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNenN.png where `using _Ptrt = _Func_base<_Ret, _Types...>`. I rest my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This boils down to the same as `struct A { int* x; };`, where in a `const A a;` you can modify *the value* of `*(a.x)` (but not where it points to). There is a level of indirection in `std::function` (from the type erasure) through which `const` is not propagated.

And no, `std::function<int()> const& f` is not pointless. In a `std::function<int()>& f` you would be able to assign a different functor to `f`, which you cannot do in the `const` case.

Comment: Yup.....that actually makes a lot of sense.....still confusing at first glance though

Comment: I believe it's a design flaw. This indirection should be an implementation detail transparent to the user, and the constness could be propagated using some metaprogramming.

Comment: @IgorR. Yes, the constness could be propagated. `std::vector` does this, `std::unique_ptr` doesn't. I feel `std::function` is not really about expressing invariants of the functor state though. Maybe we could repurpose abominable function types (i.e. `std::function<int() const>`) to distinguish?

Comment: `unique_ptr` should not propagate constness, as the regular pointer does not. And `std::function<int() const>` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @IgorR. I know. My point was that some parts of the standard library do it and some others don't. Which category `std::function` should fall into is not clear to me. And the `std::function<int() const>` was a hypothetical - of course it doesn't compile now, but would it satisfy e.g. the OP here if that could be made valid, expressing "can only be assigned functors with a `operator() const` (or stateless ones)"? (even if behind the scenes that would be quite atrocious, due to using abominable function types)?